# Iterate over two files in linux || column comparison

Tags: linux, file, unix, iterator, comparison

we have two files File1 and File 2

**File 1 columns**

**Name        Age**

abc          12

bcd    14

**File2 Columns**

**Age**

12

14

I was to Iterate over the second column of File1 and First column of File2 in single loop  and Then check if they are same.

Note:- note number of Rows in both the files are same and I am using .sh shell

Answer (score 0):

First make a temporary file from file1 that should be the same as file2.
The field name might have spaces, so remove everything until the last space.
When you have done this you can compare the files.

```
sed 's/.* //' file1 > file1.tmp
diff file1.tmp file2
```

Comment: or without the tmp and using a pipe: *sed 's/.* //' file1 | diff - file2